# HTML element not centering

Tags: css

My gender-reg (child of register-page isn't centering) it stays to the very left for some reason? I need it centered!

```
.register-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;

  ...

  .gender-reg {
    border: solid yellow;
    @include scale-to-screen((
      margin-bottom: 10px
    ))
  }

<div class="gender-reg">
  <selection-dropdown params="all: allGenderChoices"></selection-dropdown>
</div>
```

Basically what happens is everything else on the page is centered, except this element. I have zero idea as to why! Usually margin: auto centers it. I'm stuck!

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle so we can see the behavior.

Comment: Not possible, i'm using sass

Comment: i added an html bit, its basically just a div that surrounds a selection-dropdown. which is just a custom select, but using lists

Comment: @joe you can use SASS on JSFiddle. Click the cog icon in the CSS section

Comment: Where is `gender-reg` element? I cannot see it within your HTML

Comment: It's on the only div given in the example. @Caelan

Comment: Haha sorry, my mistake. I mistook it for .register-page

Comment: register-page is just a parent div. nothing special about it, i excluded from the example

Comment: Where is the CSS for `gender-reg` though? :/

Comment: @Caelan Again, it's right there in the example...

Comment: @takendarkk `.gender-reg {
      border: solid yellow;
      @include scale-to-screen((
        margin-bottom: 10px
      ))
    }` doesn't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of questions like this on SO, which would have turned up with a search such as "center div css".

Comment: forget it, I figured it out. thanks for the minus ratings..

Answer (score 0):

A width of `100%` will not center the element, Because there is no extra space.

If you set it to `50%` then it will center the element within its parent.

Try this:

```
.register-page {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
```